# No printed output data from Maxbotix Ultrasonic sensors connected to RPi. Why?

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi

```
import serial

try:
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
    print ser.isOpen() #to check port is open
    ser.read(1) #to remove first Ascii character 'R'
    ser_read = ser.read(3) #reads the remaining 3 digits
    print ser_read

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ' end'
```

Looks kind of correct, but still nothing printed after 'True' is printed but the code runs.

Comment: By "nothing printed", do you mean the program exits or freezes? Also, printing `repr`s is much saner for debugging since if your string only contains whitespace or control characters, you will get a meaningful result.

Comment: just a blinking rectangle remains at the start of a new line after 'True' is printed. It is still running  i suppose but the data isn't shown. Data should have been in the form of 'R035' where R is just a letter and '035' is the distance measured.

Comment: Okay, so for whatever reason, `ser.read(N)` is blocking indefinitely.